# Ubuntu 20.04 Show Application error

Tags: 20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 Beta and when I open Show Applications window with Super key and try to launch any app, it won't open, although the system shows that the app has been opened. Moreover, I cannot go back to the desktop from Show Applications window, it just keeps "hanging above" all other system windows and apps. Only reboot works.

Comment: I just now upgrade to 20.04 and I'm getting this too. Only solution to get back to the desktop is to log out. This happens in both X and Wayland.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt update won't solve your problem(as of now), since the package is not updated there.

Installing the latest version from github will solve.

- clone https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel
- run `make install`
- logout and login
- tweaks -> extension -> dashtopanel

Also, the same issue is addressed here
https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1131

Comment: I cloned the repo and, come into directory `dash-to-panel` but was not able to run `make install`, error: `make: *** [Makefile:58: po/ru.mo] Error 127`. Could you please help me.

Comment: @TaQuangTu 
- try sudo make install
- try make clean
..............

Error 127 means

file not found: the path you're using is incorrect. double check that the program is actually in your $PATH, or in this case, the relative path is correct.
..............
Therefore, I would suggest
` mkdir dash-to-panel ~/dash-to-panel`
`cd ~/dash-to-panel`
`make install`

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to solve the problem somehow. I tried to play with extensions, namely Dash to Dock and Dash to Panel. I deleted them and then updated to the latest version. Now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Yep.. that seems to have been the problem.  Now I just need to work out why tracker is broken and what is trying to write a MOD on my desktop but seems to have lost its font (now just in hex blocks). No idea what I installed to do that though :)